# Is managed_mapped_file able to increase file size due to allocation?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I want to work with memory mapped files using `boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file`. But cannot find in the documentation details about memory allocation by it.

Namely I want to know does `allocate()` fail with `boost::interprocess::bad_alloc` error if all memory specified during creation of `boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file` object (actually the size of the file) is already allocated or there is no enough big sequence of available memory or it just increases the size of the file.

If it fails, how can I make it to increase the size of the file (say increase two times)?

Answer (score 1):

You can grow a memory mapped file, but not while other processes have it mapped. All clients will normally have to remap the file.

Slightly related: [boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory: Grow(): Memory Reused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684861/boostinterprocessmanaged-shared-memory-grow-memory-reused/22699868#22699868)